# How to render a code snippet with javascript format by material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, highlight.js

how to format a text to a javascript code block (using React with material-ui and highlight.js)

I tried to google but I can't find any example

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please [edit] the question to add a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this wrapper for using `highlight.js` within React: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-highlight.js.

Here's a simple example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Highlight from "react-highlight.js";
function App() {
  return (
    <Highlight language="javascript">
      {`const rootElement = document.getElementById("root"); 
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);`}
    </Highlight>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

It also requires a theme to be included (e.g. `<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/styles/railscasts.css' />`) which I have put in index.html in the example.

[image: Edit highlight]

Comment: I used the `react-highlight` and it is the same usage what you mentioned `react-highlight.js`. Thank you Ryan